# Get file form windows server to linux server

Tags: java, javascript, linux, windows, ftp

I am trying to run a servlet on the Linux server which connects to the windows server and gets the files present on it.

Is there any library to get files from windows as we have just in Linux and Unix. 
As I know that using javascript only FTP is not possible.

Please let me know if you have some info to share.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just mount a Windows network share? Keyword is "Samba".

Answer (score 1):

Share your file on windows.

use jcifs library to access that. http://jcifs.samba.org/

refer to [access to file using Java with Samba JCIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771888/access-to-file-using-java-with-samba-jcifs)
for example.

Comment: The file will be dynamic and will be present in download folder of current logged in user. i will try these method and will post if it works for me