# Use java to look for the files on the network drive on windows server

Tags: java, windows

There is a third party application which drops three kind of CSV file on the windows server every night.

I need my java application to go and check for the files next day morning . if all the files are there it will read the files and insert the data into the database.

Here I know how to read the file and copy the data into db but the problem is what java libraries i can use to check if the files are present on the network drive?

COuld you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't know that the directories are network mounts.

Just use the standard Java `File` class to open the directory and examine its contents.

Answer (score 0):

slim answer is quite simple to implement and deploy: [map the window server share as a drive](http://www.wikihow.com/Map-a-Network-Drive) and access it as you would access a normal folder

if you do not want/cannot do that for permission or any other reason, look into this library which allow java to operate directly on window shares: [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/)

see this answer for a short sample: [access to file using Java with Samba JCIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771888/access-to-file-using-java-with-samba-jcifs)