# Pulling files from remote system using java Runtime.exec on mac

Tags: java, macos

All along I have been pulling the remote files using the `Runtime.exec()` first by connecting the windows remote machine using "`use net`.." and then pulling the required files. Now I have a new mac machine and I am unable to connect to that windows remote using java code. I can access the server from finder window using below command:

```
smb://userName:password@ipAddress/pathToFileOnRemote
```

but when I run this command in java code using the `Runtime.exec()` method, I get an error stating `No such file or directory`.

Is there a different way to access the file on the windows remote from mac as compared to windows?

Comment: Use a Java Samba client. Your current approach is neither cross platform nor stable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771888/access-to-file-using-java-with-samba-jcifs).

Comment: This works. Thanks for helping @BoristheSpider