# How to add SMB file link into cell?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a file which is stored in a server, the path is like: \\myserver\folder\myfile.txt

How to put this SMB address in the cell with hyperlink?

```
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE); 
link.setAddress("What to write here?");
```

When I used following code:

```
link.setAddress("\\\\myserver\\folder\\myfile.txt");
```

It returns error:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: \\myserver\folder\myfile.txt
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.validate(XSSFHyperlink.java:240)
... 2 more
```

Comment: What would you put into Excel for the same link? Then what happens if you give that to Apache POI?

Comment: It should be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771888/access-to-file-using-java-with-samba-jcifs

Comment: No, that post is on how to deal with SMB access / authentication. I want to know how to add SMB hyperlink into an Excel cell via Apache POI.

Comment: You need to encode that as a URL, try with `file:` and `/` not `\` as per the RFCs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referencing is a UNC path.  I don't know how UNC relates to SMB, but I successfully got the following code to work

```
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
link.setAddress((new File("\\\\myserver\\folder\\myfile.txt")).toURI().toString());
cell.setHyperlink(link);
```