# Copy a local folder to SMB server folder

Tags: java, samba

I am a Mac user, using Java want to copy local folder to a server folder. But I don't see the folder on the server.

```
package com.ch.chapp.GenericFunctionsLibrary;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class copyDir {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "/Users/rkan/Documents/workspace/Android-CHAPPAutomationDemo/Report";
        File srcDir = new File(source);

        String destination = "smb://mrblk/MrBlk/AutomationTestReports/CHApp";
        File destDir = new File(destination);

        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mount the smb share as a filesystem, then access the folder directly. Are you able to access the folder that way? If so it's just a file reference

Answer (score 2):

The URL format `smb://`... is only supported by the Mac desktop environment, and by Linux/Unix desktop environments such as KDE and Gnome, but not by non-desktop-aware software such as the JDK. You need to use the JCIFS library. You can find questions on Stackoverflow about how to use this library, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771888/access-to-file-using-java-with-samba-jcifs).

Alternatively, you could mount the smb share using the `mount` command-line utility, and then access it as a normal filesystem, but AFAIK the initial mount requires sudo access.